# Can't find installed synaptics

Tags: 13.04, synaptic

I just installed synaptics for touchpad via Ubuntu software center but I can't find it at all: not in the "start" menu or in the settings. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Alan if I am not mistaken the Synaptics Touchpad should be found under System > Preferences > Mouse under the Touchpad tab. This instruction is according to [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad) on help.ubuntu.com. I hope this helps. Any more questions just comment.

Comment: there is no such menu.

Comment: @AlanDert can you confirm that you have installed? open software centre and check under installed. if its there it may be another problem and I might have to ammend my answer